# How to overwrite Shopify's Loox app css code so I can style it the way I want on website?

Tags: css, shopify

I have installed the Loox app from shopify (https://loox.app/) on shopify's minimal theme. Their app is overriding my css code and resetting to their default code when I try to change it. How do I override their css so mine takes over and I can style it on my page the way I want?

** I have tried !important and does not work

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow Gina, you'd better ask much more detailed questions in this website. Also, your questions must contain a full list of steps that you have done plus the step in which an issue occurs. It is not recommended to ask general questions which mostly can be solved by searching the net, here.

Comment: I actually tried googling it and finding how to fix it before I posted here.( 2 days of googling) I am trying to find a way to overwrite loox css code so I can resize the pictures as they have them in different sizes. The Loox app css overrides my css no matter what I do. I am looking for a section of code or something that I can input into my code that will allow my css to override theirs and change the picture size how I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always ask the App developers to fix their App so it does not break your theme. You can always uninstall Apps like that that break your theme. Complain to Shopify if you get no traction with them. Basically, Apps should never cause your theme to change and look bad, if they are designed correctly.

Comment: I am trying to change the picture sizing as they have it set to show picture sizes in random different sizes. I want the pictures all the same size.

Comment: image sizing in Liquid is rarely the domain of CSS. Images in Shopify Liquid are usually rendered with Liquid abstractions like large, medium, small etc.